# Is there a way to list all calls of equals() of a certain class using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, equals

I'm confronted with the following problem at the moment:

I have a certain class in which the equals() - Method is overridden. However I'm not sure if it is ever being used (either in my or in one of my collegues projects). Is there a way to find out?
When I search for references, well, it just gives me ALL references to the Object equals() - Method (which are quite a few). There surely must be an easier way than scan through all of them...

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 7):

You're asking Eclipse to solve an impossible task.

To figure out if a particular overridden method is called or not is not *statically decidable*, which is why Eclipse over approximates the response.

Assume you have some field `Object o` and that you at some point do `o.equals(...)`. To determine whether or not `o` could ever refer to a `YourClass` object requires that you determine the runtime type of `o` along every possible execution path, which simply can't be done statically.

The reason why it is impossible is quite similar to why the compiler rejects the following code:

```
Object o = "hello";
System.out.println(o.length());
```

The best thing you can do is probably debug your program, either by setting a break point or by throwing for instance an UnsupportedOperationException from within the equals method.

Comment: I think the question was about referencies in the workspace projects, not runtime calls

Comment: That's how I interpreted the question too.

Comment: ah I see; but if I hilite an overridden equals() invocation in a class and press F3, eclipse correctly goes to the overriding method definition, not Objects equals(). So why couldn't that be repeated on every file in the workspace?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. I'll have to do it in the old tedious fashion. Thanks everyone

Comment: your example makes me think even more that runtime type has nothing to do with this question. you could argue that tracking the super() calls in a subclass overriding the method again could be cumbersome (but not impossible). even if the subclass downcasts and calls equals(), in that line the local variable is statically identifiable as the target class. So can you provide a concrete example which can make me understand your point?

Comment: and actually, in my current workspace, if i search for references of Object.equals(Object) i get 510 occurrences, on String.equals(Object) I get 4119 and on mycustomclass.equals(Object) i get 8. It seems pretty much its working fine.

Comment: The point is that you can't in general tell if a Object.equals will infact call mycustomclass.equals.

Comment: What you're missing is that the searches for references are only finding references that are statically knowable. In other words, cases where the compiler knows that you have an instance of `MyClass` and the code with that reference is explicitly calling `equals()`. However, since `equals()` is defined on `Object`, it could be called on any `Object` variable that might or might not have been assigned an instance of `MyClass`. For example, there are things like collections which call `equals()` on their contents but don't have any idea what the class of the contents is/are.

Comment: @E-Riz sorry, yep i think i know as well how incapsulation is implemented in java; what i tried to say is that telling "it's impossible" to someone who wants to find references of a method call in his code, is a bit of overshooting, compared to "you can use eclipse search, but beware it wont/cant find runtime invocations of the overriden method".

Comment: @guido, in the context of the origianl question, the answer "it's not possible" is definitely NOT overshooting. The question already states that the simple references search doesn't yield what the asker wants, and he says "There surely must be an easier way than scan through all of them..." - the answer is, "No, there's not."

Comment: By the way, what I described is not encapsulation, it's polymorphism.

Comment: *"You're asking Eclipse to solve an impossible task."* I beg to differ. In fact, Eclipse can already distinguish between two different calls: The call to the overriding method and the call to the overridden method. The asker (and I) merely wants this distinction reflected in the Call Hierarchy tree.

Answer (score 3):

Seems java is broken in that respect. So you need to do it the hard way and hope to catch all occurrences.

- Create a copy of your class
- Delete the old class
- Fix all compiler-errors by renaming one by one.
- Look for occurrences where the class is used as key for maps
- Look for collections of the class ( indexOf(), contains() )
- Look for calls to equals() or hashCode() of the class
- Hope you didnt miss something

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a method that would reliably do this purely through static analysis (I doubt one exists).

A practical method that *might* help is to set a breakpoint on the first line of the `equals()` method, and start the program in the Eclipse debugger. Whenever the method is called, Eclipse will break into the debugger. At this point you'll be able to examine the call stack to see who has called the method.

To do this effectively you'd have to have some idea of which code paths can be expected to call the method. If you are unable to trigger the method, this doesn't prove that no one uses it.

Comment: And then what? Execute _every possible code path_ in debug mode?

Comment: @Asaph: With respect, you're very welcome to post better suggestions.

Comment: I was going to but I think @aioobe has the answer (which is it can't be done). I upvoted his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Select method name in Eclipse -> Package explorer or Outline view and click F4. 
Alternatively you can select method -> right click -> Open Call Hierarchy
This will show all members calling this method in your workspace.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

What about modifying the overridden equals to something like :

```
log.debug // Whatever you want
return this == obj;
```

Which give you the classic Object equals ? Or maybe a super.equals if you extends some class?